# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for papplet

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, papplet

I'm having issues getting processing set up. I have another project I pulled that uses it perfectly well, but when I try to create a new project, I keep running into errors. I have all my libraries set up, and I'm using processing 3.5.4, although I've also tried the most recent version. Everything is added to the build path, so I don't understand why PApplet isn't being found
[image]

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class                 embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet
```

upon going to run configurations and clicking "show command line"

```
    C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.9.v20231028-0858\jre\bin\javaw.exe
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    -Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8
    -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
    -p "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\core.jar"
    -classpath "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\bin;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\jogl-all.jar;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\MidPose.jar;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\embodiedInteractionDance\libs\jogl-all-noawt-2.2.4.jar"
    -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle
```

am I correct to understand that this is an issue with the core jar?
I've cleared out all existing run configs and tried again, same error

MovingRectangle

```
package embodiedInteractionDance;
import processing.core.*;

public class MovingRectangle extends PApplet{
// The argument passed to main must match the class name
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main(MovingRectangle.class.getName());
}

// method used only for setting the size of the window
public void settings(){
    size(400,400);   
   
}

// identical use to setup in Processing IDE except for size()
public void setup(){
    background(0);
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(10);
}

// identical use to draw in Processing IDE
public void draw(){
    line(0, 0, 500, 500);
}}
```

UsingProcessing

```
package shapes;
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class UsingProcessing extends PApplet {

//  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
//  JFrame overlay = new JFrame("Mouse Listener");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main(UsingProcessing.class.getName());
    //      canvas.addMouseListener();
}
public void settings(){
    size(1000,1000);
}

public void setup(){
    strokeWeight(1);
    //moved the static objects from draw() to here
    //hair
    fill(0);
    ellipse(width/7*4, height/7, width-100, 350);
    rect(width/7, 200, width-100,height);

    //head
    fill(210,180,140);
    ellipse(height/2+50,width/2+50,height-100,width-100);
    //eyes
    fill(0); 
    ellipse(width/3,height/3,100,100);
    ellipse(width/3*2,height/3,100,100);

}

public void draw(){

    //pupils (leave them growing, fun effect)
    fill(120,50,240);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(width/3,height/3,second(),second());
    ellipse(width/3*2,height/3,second(),second());
    
    //nose
    stroke(255, 102, 0);
    strokeWeight(5);
    noFill();
    curve(width/2, height/2-50, width/2, height/2+100, width/2+50, height/2+100, width/2+75, height/2+150);

    //eyebrows
    fill(175,50,75);
    triangle(width/4, height/4, width/4, height/4+50,  width/4+150, height/4+50 );
    triangle(width/4*3-150, height/4, width/4*3-150, height/4+50,  width/4*3+100, height/4+50 );

    //mouth
    fill(255,50,100);
    stroke(200,50,50);
    arc(width/2, height/3*2, width/3*2-width/3, second(), 0, PI, CHORD);

}}
```

Comment: Add code and error messages always as text never as image

Comment: I don't know Processing, but I don't see a single jar with the substring 'processing' in its name...

Comment: `processing.core.PApplet` is missing when you run it, but no error is shown at the import statement for this class. So there is something wrong with your launch configuration (in the launch configuration you can override which libraries should be used. In _Run > Run Configurations..._ please delete your launch configuration and try again. If this does not help, show the command line (in the launch configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_) and tell which library JAR contains `processing.core.PApplet`.

Comment: @g00se processing is a larger package that include core, glugen, and jogl. It runs successfully / is implemented successfully with an identical set up (as far as jars) in another project

Comment: @howlger I've just added the command line return, I don't understand how to interpret it though

Comment: @KMM thank you. *am I correct to understand that this is an issue with the core jar?* Yes. *I've just added the command line return, I don't understand how to interpret it though* `PApplet` is likely to be in core.jar - which is NOT in the classpath. So as @howlger says, it's likely to be your run config. Since I don't use Eclipse I can't help

Comment: According to the command line, `core.jar` is on the module path (`-p`), not on the classpath, but this should not be a problem. The command line is for running `embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle`, but the screenshot shows the code of `shapes.UsingProcessing` (also the _Console_ view is about `shapes.UsingProcessing`). Which class do you want to run, `shapes.UsingProcessing` or `embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle` (please show your code as text)? /cc @g00se

Comment: Doh, missed `-p` ;)

Comment: Ah, I was trying to run using processing because I know that works in another project, I'll add both UsingProcessing and MovingRectangle to my main power now @howlger

Comment: @g00se sorry required to notify users in two comments

Comment: Please focus on one class only. In the screenshot the red highlighting looks like you did _Coverage As > Java Application_ instead of _Run As > Java Application_. Please, in _Run > Run Configurations..._ delete your launch configurations, in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Libraries_ move `core.jar` to the _Classpath_, do _Project > Clean..._, choose one class with a main method, right-click and choose _Run As > Java Application_. If you still face issue, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @howlger yes I accidentally did a coverage as run, but all subsequent runs were not that and I don't know how to make it stop showing the red--moving the core jar worked ty

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it's working now. The red highlighting of the cover can be removed in the _Coverage_ view, which is located on the right behind the _Console_ view in your screenshot.

Comment: @g00se It turns out I was wrong and `core.jar` on the modulepath is the actual problem here.

Comment: @howlger - Ah OK. Any ideas why that should be a problem?

Comment: @g00se Maybe `core.jar` has a `module-info.class` without exporting the package containing the required class. But in this case I would assume that Eclipse would display an error at the _import_ statement, which is obviously not the case according to the screenshot. `PApplet` seems to use reflection which might also affected by `core.jar` on the modulepath, but then a different error with a stack trace would be more likely. Actually, I don't know what the real reason is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the command line, your **`core.jar` is on the modulepath** (`-p`), not on the classpath (`-classpath`). This might be a problem as a JAR on the module path is treated as a separate encapsulated module. In contrast, all your other JARs are on the classpath and therefore treated as a single unencapsulated module, the so-called *unnamed module*.

In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path tab*** ***Libraries***, **move `core.jar`** from the *Modulepath* **to the *Classpath*** via drag and drop.